# Comparing Local Powershell Modules to Modules in Remote Repository

Tags: powershell

I am exploring automating the publishing of Powershell modules to our local repository.

How can I compare a module that exists locally (that is found in $env:PSModulePath), and one in a remote repository?

I would like to both compare the version numbers and detect if the module code is the same.

How possible is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare the versions, you can use `Get-InstalledModule` to list and retrieve the installed version(s) of local modules, and `Find-Module` to search your configured repositories for the latest available module. Then you just compare versions. Using the `AWSPowerShell.NetCore` module as a sample:

```
$installedVersion ( Get-InstalledModule -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore ).Version | Select-Object -First 1 # More than 1 version can be returned if installed
$upstreamVersion ( Find-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.Core ).Version

# returns $true if out of date, $false if not 
$outOfDate = $installedVersion -lt $upstreamVersion
```

But to compare the code, you would have to download the module using `Save-Module` to store it at some arbitrary path, then diff both the local copy and new copy to inspect any changes. You can also check the version of the modules themselves by looking at the first level of the module directory - the module code will be in a folder named whatever the module version is.

To check for changes within the code (using `AWSPowerShell.NetCore` again as an example), you can use `Compare-Object` to diff the module directories:

```
Save-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore -Path /tmp

# Use whatever the latest installed version directory you have here is
$installedModule = gci '/home/bender/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AWSPowerShell.NetCore/1.2.3.4'

# Use the version directory which appears here
$upstreamModule = gci /tmp/AWSPowerShell.NetCore/1.2.3.5 
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $installedModule -DifferenceObject $upstreamModule
```

Comment: In order to check whether any of the files (as opposed to just filenames) had changed, I used this:
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $installedModule.Hash -DifferenceObject $upstreamModule.Hash